# Goodness of fit

Tags: statistics

Define X as the number of underfilled bottles from a filling operation in a carton of 24 bottles. Of 75 cartons inspected, the following observations on X are recorded:

For 0, 1, 2, 3 corresponding frequencies are 43, 23, 8, 1

Based on these 75 observations, is a binomial distribution an appropriate model? Perform a goodness-of-fit procedure with $alpha$ = 0.05

I solved goodness-of-fit problems before but with this one I could not find a way to struct the problem.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This does go a bit beyond what is clearly stated in many texts.
Here is some guidance:

"Categories" are 0, 1, 2, 3.  Respective "Observed frequencies" are 
43, 23, 8, 1.  Respective "Expected frequencies" are obtained from
$Binom(24, \hat p),$ with $\hat p$ estimated as total observed under-filled bottles divided
by the total number of bottles $75(24)$ seen. There were
$0(43) + 1(23) + 2(8) + 1(3) = 42$ under-filled bottles
so $\hat p =  0.02333.$
Interpret "3" as "3 or more" and be sure the expected
frequency for that category is not too small.

If you have $k$ categories and estimate one parameter (here $p$), then DF for chi-sq statistic is $k - 2=4-2=2$

*Addendum:*  As a check, I got the following, and eventually
concluded a binomial model is a
good fit:

```
  Cat     0        1      2      3
  Obs    43       23      8      1
  Exp    41.564   24.825  7.117  ????
```

The Expected values are from multiplying probabilities
of $Binom(24, \hat p)$ by $75$ cartons; they must sum to 75.

Comment: I'm not understanding how you're determining p still.

Comment: Sorry, fixing some typos, and adding a bit of explanation.